# Why is "internationalization" shortened to "i18n"?

Tags: internationalization, abbreviation

When people discuss about internationalization, they use the word "i18n" more often. For first time I didn't get what they are referring to by "i18n", then I came to know that it means "internationalization".

So wanted to know why internationalization = i18n.

Comment: [i18n](http://google.com/search?q=i18n), first hit.

Comment: Can "an" be represented as "a00n"?

Comment: Dam i hate this abbreviation system, if its the first time your see it you have no chance to guess what it stands for. i18n, l10n, g11n, l12y or k8s I'm sure there are more are more out there that will bug me in the future!

Comment: @BenjaminManns the question is if it should be `a00n` or `a0n`?

Comment: To me it's less an abbreviation and more an optimization. Long paths can still cause problems in some systems. Microsoft only recently started allowing file paths [greater than 260 characters](https://mspoweruser.com/ntfs-260-character-windows-10/).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization

> 18 stands for the number of letters
>   between the first i and last n  in
>   internationalization, a usage coined
>   at DEC in the 1970s or 80s

Comment: Is "i18n" internationally used, or it abbreviated differently in languages where the cognate has a different number of letters?

Answer (score 39):

.

```
            1    1  1
   1---5----0----5--8
 i|nternationalizatio|n  == i18n

            1
   1---5----0
 l|ocalizatio|n          == l10n
```

See also http://www.w3.org/2001/12/Glossary#I18N.

Comment: Aaaah... the number of letters between i and n then...

Answer (score 8):

18 is the number of letters between i and n in **internationalization** word.

This contraction is an [English numerical contraction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_numerical_contractions);
contractions were the ellipsis of all but the first and last character is shown by the number of omitted characters

Comment: Muphry's Law: Any text commenting on a spelling or grammar error will have a similar error itself.

Answer (score 5):

Because they didn't feel like writing the whole word.

`i18n`
it's `"i"` followed by 18 characters ('nternationalizatio', count them) and a `"n"` and that's it.

Comment: Um, that's why spell checkers were invented?

Answer (score 0):

I18n is a numeronym, not an abbreviation. It's just a shorthand that uses numbers, is widely accepted, and serves as a synonym for the original. It's much easier saying "24/7" when referring to 24 hours a day, seven days of the week. Or even "9/11" to refer to a specific event.